# How to permanently curse an existing item?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, crafting, curses

By permanently, I don't mean 'until dispelled', which can be achieved by using upcast *bestow curse*. I want to make those items that cannot be unattuned, except by casting *remove curse* on the wielder. I want to make the curse unremovable by *remove curse*. In short, similar to your traditional cursed magic item.

**Are there rule, guidance, or precedent to convince my DM?**

Of course there are DM rulings, but it will be helpful if the process can be described mechanically or narratively.

My question asks for *cursing* an existing item and is different from [How do you make cursed items as a PC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135735/how-do-you-make-cursed-items-as-a-pc).

The item is an NPC's (and possibly already magical, although we're not sure) and we want to imbue it with an *autocorrect curse* (for their speech).

Comment: While not necessary to answer the question, it would help for us to understand *why* you want to do it, I think. Are you planning to give a Greek gift to some NPC or something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make cursed items as a PC?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/135735/how-do-you-make-cursed-items-as-a-pc)

Comment: @HellSaint edited in. It's a prank/revenge on a king that 'deceived' us using fine print on a contract. It is really a fun campaign.

Comment: @Anagkai I don't know how that question escape my search (maybe because I use 'curse' instead 'cursed'), but I think my question is a bit different. It does partially answer my question, but missing explanation when the item already exists and possibly magical.

Comment: The questions are slightly different. One is for creating a magic item, the other is for cursing an existing magic item.

Comment: I think there's something odd in the first paragraph; it says ""cannot be unattuned, except by Remove Curse" and then on the next line "I want ot make it unremovable by remove curse". And then says "like a traditional cursed magic item", which (in D&D 5e anyway) *can* be removed by remove curse. What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @Erik 5e cursed magic item cannot be 'uncursed', even with Remove curse - which only allows unattunement (because you cannot unattune from cursed magic item normally). Its curse can only be removed via DM fiat or when its description says so (or other spell/means specifically say so)

Comment: Ah, you mean you want the item to be removable from the victim with Remove Curse, but not have the item be returned to a normal item with Remove Curse? That makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of item that can't be removed is against concept of most spells and effects and items in D&D 5. So, if you want an item that "can't be removed by remove curse" - it's close to impossible and whatever such item would do - it likely would belong to area of 'legendary' things, some of which break the normal rules. And certainly, would be a bit too overkill for a prank.

But, technically speaking - there are several ways.

First - there is a Wish spell. 9th level, alters reality. Probably it can alter the king himself to make him stutter or that he is an idiot each time, when he says his name. You need to be at least 17th level to do it (on par with level requirements for creating legendary items) and willing to face consequences of wasting potentially game world changing spell on something that trivial.

Second - you can find a friendly god. Or at least friendly cleric of a god, who would be sympathetic to your cause. (Probably some trickster god, if he won't decide that king did right thing by deceiving you, or some god of law, if king had done it unlawfully). And your cleric friend needs to be at least level 10 to be able to pray for Divine Intervention (level 20 for instant response, otherwise you may spend several days or weeks paraying) - it's a bit random and it's not guaranteed that you'd achieve the desired effect - but it depends on creativity of your DM.

Third - while it's not exactly creating a cursed item - to achieve your desired effect you can use geas. 5th level spell that forces target to obey your command. It's not permanent - 60 days if cast with level 5, a year with 7th or 8th, so you may need a way to recast it every now and then and target may pass the initial save or just endure 5d10 damage each day. Also, you need to somehow hold king within 60 feet from you for a minute as you cast the spell and make sure that he won't remember/identify you, unless you want to end up as 'most wanted people in all surrounding lands'.

Fourth - work with DM, talk with DM, discuss your desires with DM. All of those ways require it anyway and his input on whether god would interdict on your behalf, whether Wish spell may have such effect and how you can stealthily put Geas on the king. If your DM is creative - he may come up with some way to do it, to craft a special spell, perform some ritual and so on. If your DM is against such prank - he would find a way to stop you from doing it even with a Wish and, potentially, it may lead to ruining the game for both sides. Honestly, it's one of the worst things that may happen with game - forcing DM to do something that he doesn't want to do.

Comment: When I say 'cannot be removed' I refer to the curse. The curse should not be able to be removed by Remove Curse. Remove Curse only breaks attunement. I don't know exactly whether a cursed item can be unequipped, but I do know its attunement can't be voluntarily broken.